# git clone --bare <remote-uri> does not copy the files from remote uri

Tags: git

I want to make cloned repository as bare at the same time i am cloning.

So I am using the command as:

```
git clone --bare <remote_uri>
```

But it is not copying the files from remote, just creating a directory as bare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning as bare will not create a working directory but it will only create a Local Repository i.e. file which are available in .git directory.

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of the `--bare` option.

If you want a clone with a work tree just do `git clone <remote-uri>` without `--bare`.